# Installing HBase apart from cloudera

Tags: hbase, cloudera

We have a cluster of 15 nodes with cloudera 5.5.2 installed which comes with HBase version 1.0.0 ([Version detail](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_previous.html?scroll=topic_7#concept_mlz_n43_w5_unique_2)) but we need 1.1.3 as there are some [issues](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kylin-issues/201510.mbox/%3CJIRA.12906166.1445327799000.5797.1445328567711@Atlassian.JIRA%3E) with 1.0.0 so we need to install HBase 1.1.3 and keeping all the other services of cloudera as it is.

**My Question**

Is there a way to install HBase version apart from cloudera.

I tried installing Apache HBase on some other folder with different user but got an issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/HBaseConfTool : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool.  Program will exit.
```

I have already removed HBase from cloudera and no HBase service are running on the cluster but it is still loading the jars of HBase 1.0.0.

Comment: did you replace cloudera jar with the hbase jar?

Comment: it worked after removing the jars of cloudera from node and renamed the folder of hbase

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this. There are just too many dependencies between HBase and other Hadoop services, like Zookeeper, HDFS, and YARN.

I can only advise you to upgrade the cluster to the desired version